# Send data to server side from client

Tags: javascript

I'm currently creating a simple web-based data visualization tool. I basically want to be able to send the user selections to the server (which I have created using express) to query the database. The problem is I am not sure how to send the data to the server and then receive it at the other end in order to do this.

I want the data to be sent to the server on the click of a button

```js
var data = {
    Admission_type: "";
    Gender: "";
    Max_age: 89,
    Min_age: 0
};

$( "#PlotBtn" ).click(function() { 
   
});
```

Comment: make an ajax request and send it to some route. then use this route in your server file to access the variable data.

Answer (score 1):

The most common vanilla JS way of sending data to a server is with to make a [XMLHttpRequest (XHR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). It seems like you're trying to pass an object, and JSON is perhaps the most flexible way of sending data to and from a server. So the simplest piece of code that would send data to the server is something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest; 
xhr.open("GET", "https://yourserver.domain.com/data"); 
xhr.send();
```

This however will only send the information and it has no way of handling the response. There are many ways to go about this, as well as many options on how the information is sent, but this is the barebones you need to get the response.

```
xhr.onload = function(){
  console.log(xhr.response);
};
```

Take a look at the documentation linked above to see more options and other events you can listen to.

Comment: And how do i receive the data on server side?

Comment: That depends on what server technology you are using on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a lot of way to send data through the network. As explained @Asinus, the most common way is to use `XMLHttpRequest` (aka `xhr`) but the most modern browsers offers better way to achieve the purpose. One of them is the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It is more powerful than its predecessor xhr!

I recommend you to take a look to this [blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) about Fetch. Here, an example of use:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
  method: 'get'
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.json()); // Response, everything is fine
}).cath(err => {
  console.log(err); // Failure: an error occurred
});
```

In your case, if you want to send data to your server, you have to make a `POST` request to be [Restful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).